# function to change cases of certain characters in a string

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

I have a string and I would like to change the first letter and every alternate letter into upper case and also make use of list comprehension to transform my nested for loops.

I have the string and I managed to split it up into words and using the nested for loop, make the necessary transformations of letters into upper case but I am not able to capture the results into the correct array from the nested for loop and I am also not able to replace the nested for loop with a list comprehension.

## input string

```py
st = 'This is my expected function that is supposed to convert the first character and every alternate character into upper case'
```

## converted the input string into words

```py
words = [b for b in st.split()]

for i in range(0,len(words)):
    temp_word = list(words[i])
    for j in range(0,len(temp_word),2):
        temp_word[j] = temp_word[j].upper()
        print(temp_word)
```

Input: 'This is my expected function that is supposed to convert the first 
character and every alternate character into upper case'

Output: 'ThIs Is My ExPeCtEd FuNcTiOn ThAt Is SuPpOsEd To CoNvErT ThE FiRsT ChArAcTeR AnD EvErY AlTeRnAtE ChArAcTeR InTo UpPeR CaSe'

Comment: Could you consider improving the formatting so that it is easier to figure out your program?

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will help community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `join` with list comprehension:

```
' '.join([''.join([char.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else char for i, char in enumerate(word)]) for word in st.split()])
```

**Example**:

```
st = 'This is my expected function that is supposed to convert the first character and every alternate character into upper case'

print(' '.join([''.join([char.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else char for i, char in enumerate(word)]) for word in st.split()]))
# ThIs Is My ExPeCtEd FuNcTiOn ThAt Is SuPpOsEd To CoNvErT ThE FiRsT ChArAcTeR AnD EvErY AlTeRnAtE ChArAcTeR InTo UpPeR CaSe
```

Comment: Thanks. It works!! I am going to take some time out though to understand this code.